# Chapter map with latex

Tags: chapters, chapter-page

I want to write the following map of chapters in my thesis.
But how can I write down such a diagram in latex ?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

I entered this code, but I cannot write diagonal arrow.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto,]
 % Nodes
 \node (21) {2.1};
 \node[right=of 21] (51) {5.1};
 \node[right=of 51] (22a) {2.2};
 \node[above=of 22a] (22) {2.2};
 \node[right=of 22] (23) {2.3};
 \node[right=of 23] (24) {2.4};
 \node[right=of 24] (31) {3.1};
 \node[right=of 31] (32) {3.2};
 \node[right=of 32] (33) {3.3};
 \node[above=of 31] (41) {4.1};
 \node[right=of 41] (42) {4.2};
 \node[right=of 42] (43) {4.3};
 \node[above=of 24] (25) {2.5};

 % Arrows
 \draw[->] (21) -- (51);
 \draw[->] (51) -- (22a);
 \draw[->] (22a) -- (22);
 \draw[->] (22) -- (23);
 \draw[->] (23) -- (24);
 \draw[->] (24) -- (31);
 \draw[->] (31) -- (32);
 \draw[->] (32) -- (33);
 \draw[->] (31) -- (41);
 \draw[->] (41) -- (42);
 \draw[->] (42) -- (43);
 \draw[->] (24) -- (25);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Use Tikz: it‘s very simple to do it manually. However, I‘m not sure if you really add value for your reader, i.e. your structure may need some rethinking.

Comment: Look for keywords `below` and `above` in the pgfmanual together with its combinations of `right`etc., or `xshift` or `shift` . Right now you position everything on a line. // BTW, a screenshot of your codes result might be useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, with some variation for your inspiration, and ignoring your `(22a)`:

[image: result]

Unless you really want your crankshaft-like positioning, the keys seem to be to:

- focus on the main path first (2.1 .. 3.3)
- place the diagonal elements as needed, here via positioning, while `xshift` etc. are options as well, see [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702972/chapter-map-with-latex#comment1748768_702972)
- same for drawing: main-chain first, side chains after that

To give you some more ideas I introduced these variations, which may or may not help the reader of your thesis:

- a nicer arrow tip in my view `>={Stealth},`
- dashed and dotted lines
- colored lines
- some label next to a line

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=1cm, auto,
    >={Stealth},    
    ]
     % ~~~ Nodes, left to right = main path ~~~
     \node (21) {2.1};
     \node[right=of 21] (51) {5.1};
     \node[right=of 51] (23) {2.3};
     \node[right=of 23] (24) {2.4};
     \node[right=of 24] (31) {3.1};
     \node[right=of 31] (32) {3.2};
     \node[right=of 32] (33) {3.3};
     
     % ~~~ 2.2. chains ~~~~~~~
     \node[below=of 51] (22) {2.2};
     \node[above=of 24] (25) {2.5};
     
     % ~~~↑ 4.x chain ~~~~~~~~~~~
     \node[above=of 32] (41) {4.1};
     \node[right=of 41] (42) {4.2};
     \node[right=of 42] (43) {4.3};
     

     % ~~~ Arrows, main path ~~~~~~~
     \draw[->] (21) -- (51);
     \draw[->] (51) -- (23);
     \draw[->] (23) -- (24);
     \draw[->] (24) -- (31);
     \draw[->] (31) -- (32);
     \draw[->] (32) -- (33);
    
     % ~~~ 2.x chain, with some variation ~~~~~~~
     \draw[->,dashed] (22) -- node[right,pos=.3] {good reason} (23);
     \draw[->,dotted] (23) -- (25); 
     
     % ~~~ 4.x chain, with some variation ~~~
     \draw[->,red]  (31) -- (41);
     \draw[->,blue] (41) -- (42);
     \draw[->,green](42) -- (43);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Really helpful and beautiful diagram, Thank you so much.